# Mongoose setting Object IDs in updateMany

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to add IDs to many object inside of array inside. Assume that my schema looks like this:

```
{
   _id: something,
   property:value,
   animals: [
     {
       dogs: [
         { name: 'Dog1' },
         { name: 'Dog2' }
       ],
       cats: [
         { name: 'Cat1' },
         { name: 'Cat2' }
       ]
     }
   ]
}
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
{
   _id: something,
   property:value,
   animals: [
     {
       dogs: [
         { name: 'Dog1', _id: uniqueID },
         { name: 'Dog2', _id: uniqueID }
       ],
       cats: [
         { name: 'Cat1', _id: uniqueID },
         { name: 'Cat2', _id: uniqueID }
       ]
     }
   ]
}
```

My code

```
db.collection('collectionName').updateMany(
  { animals: { $ne: [] } },
       {
          $set: {
            'animals.$[].cats.$[]._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            'animals.$[].dogs.$[]._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
          }
       }
 );
```

It works but IDs are exactly the same. How to achieve unique IDs?

Answer (score 1):

That happens because `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` is a client-side function.  It is executed while building the query, and only the value returned by the function call is included in the request submitted to the server.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how can I achieve unique IDs?

Comment: You will need to generate each ID separately.  Since you have an array of objects nested in an array of objects it may not be simple to determine how many pets there are in a general way, so it may be simpler to just retrieve each document, update each pet with and ID and then .save